# Flex integration with SMS not working when switched from Proxy Service directly to Studio Flow

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am experimenting with Twilio Flex. I have setup project from Flex template to get started and it worked fine.
When I go to Flex Phone Number configuration I can see incoming messages are routed to Flex Proxy Service.

1. I don't understand quite well how Flex Proxy Service is integrated with Studio Messaging Flow. I can see my SMS messages in Messaging Flow log's but I do not know where exactly Proxy Service is configured to route messages to this flow
2. When I tried to change Flex Phone Number configuration so that when new message comes in Studio Flow (Messaging Flow) is called directly it stopped working and I could not see my messages popping up in Flex agent dashboard any more.

Obviously proxy service is doing something else in the background (other than routing to respective studio flow). Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Proxy is used to orchestrate messages from multiple channels to the Flex agent UI. In the background it bridges messages from a messaging channel like SMS to a chat session. It is not necessary to configure the Proxy service manually, Flex automatically does it for you. You can configure a phone number for Flex on the [Flex Management Console](https://www.twilio.com/console/flex/numbers). On the same page you can link a messaging channel to a Studio flow. This flow is triggered whenever a new conversation is created.

[image]

You cannot configure a phone number directly with a Studio Flow to use it with Flex. The Flow for a channel is always configured (selected from the drop-down) on the [Flex Management Console](https://www.twilio.com/console/flex/numbers).